# do all quattros have shafts connecting front and rear axles

Tags: engine, wheels, audi, 4wd

I have recently purchased a 2009 Audi A5 Quattro, and in looking underneath the car there does seem to be a place for a shaft to connect the front axle to the rear axle (which you would expect) but there doesnt seem to be any there... is this normal?

Comment: Could you post a picture of what you're seeing?  We would certainly expect to see a driveshaft running to the aft end of the car: http://fotos.autozeitung.de/1024x768/images/bildergalerie/2009/06/az14_09_094_Tech_DiffAudi.jpg

Comment: for it to be 4wd there has to be a method linking the front wheels to the rear wheels.  If there is no shaft between the front and rear diffs then the likely answer is no.  You can ask a dealer to check if yours is actually a quattro or not by supplying the VIN.

Comment: @Mauro, actually if you have the VIN and the owner's manual, you can usually decode it yourself.

Comment: @Bob Cross, how do you mean, what do you look for?

Comment: You can decode your VIN by referring to the codes in the owners manual.  You can also use some web services like the following: http://www.audivindecoder.com/vins/waudk78t59a020347/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All Audi Qauttro's have a driveshaft that connects the front differential with the rear differential.

Your car does not have 4wd if it does not have a driveshaft.

In my country (Denmark) you can add the car to your profile at https://my.audi.com and add the VIN of the car. Then you can see all information about the car including factory installed options etc.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question, it seems like you didn't buy a Quattro. You bought a FWD car, unless Audi invented some way of transferring power without a drive shaft :(.

You might want to talk to the person you bought it from, and bring it to their attention.

Comment: Agreed. Worst case is that there was something wrong with the 4wd system and the guy ripped out the drive shaft to hide the fact.

Comment: Look beneath the rear of the car. Check if there is a rear differential or not.

Answer (score 4):

Check under the rear of the car you should be able to see the rear differential. it is the aluminium finned item between the rear wheels

[image: A5 Quattro]

If you don't have on then you definitely don't have a quattro, you should also check the VIN to make sure. The driveshaft it self is kinda hard to see depending on the angle.

If your car was sold to you as a quattro and it isn't then you definitely need to take it back.